# PHP File Upload, files disappearing from /tmp before move_uploaded_files

Tags: php, file, upload, file-upload

I have a very basic upload script, probably lifted straight off the php.net/move_upload_files function page.

`move_uploaded_file()` is failed because it cannot find the tmp file in the tmp folder. But I KNOW that it is being put there, but is removed before `move_upload_file()` can deal with it in my script. I know it is being put there since I can see a file in there when a large file is being posted to the server.

Also `$_FILES`contains correct details for the file I have just uploaded.

Had anyone have any idea why the temporary file is being removed from /tmp before I have a chance to handle it?

Here is the basic code that I am using.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_file))
{
    $result['error'] = 'false';
    $result['file_loc'] = $upload_file;
}
else
{
    $result['error'] = 'true';
}
```

The output of `print_r($_FILES)` looks like

```
[userfile] => Array
(
    [name] => switchsolo.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpIyKRl5
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 6690
)
```

But /tmp/phpIyKRl5 simply isn't there.

Comment: Please post your HTML form. I think the problem is in your HTML.

Comment: What is the exact message move_uploaded_file() gives you?

Comment: Please post the message from your error log

Comment: Do you have root control over the server? If you don't, check with the system administrator there may be a garbage collect service installed that allows you to write to a file but the moment the file lock is released (once the file uploads) the file is deleted.

If you have access (SSH or TTY) i suggest using watch -d -n0.1 ls -la and seeing when in the process the file disappears

Comment: Just to update, the form is actually generated by Javascript, since this is an AjaxUploader that POSTs to an injected iFrame on the page. I am certain that the error is not coming from any of the HTML or submission of the form itself. 

Ben James: Do you mean my Apache error log?

Comment: In response to Zyris, I have used the watch command, I can visually see the file uploading, but it disappears as soon as the file has uploaded.

Comment: Can you switch to normal, form based, non-Ajax uploading for a second and see whether the same thing happens?

Comment: did you even check the destination folder location you passed to the `move_uploaded_file()`? maybe it's already **moved** there so why should you check the temporary location?

Comment: I have fixed this, it was me being a moron, I had the path to the destination file wrong, I have beaten myself with a stick and have worn a sandwich board stating that I'm a prick, so sorry to waste everyones time.

Answer (score 10):

1) Are the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize holding higher value than the size of the file you are trying to upload?

2) Does your uploading script take longer time to execute than the value of the max_execution_time variable allows?

3) I assume your uploading script doesn't consume as much memory as the memory_limit variable allows. When the client is uploading the file to the server, then the server is probably holding some of it in memory while doing so. I'm not sure if it somehow affects the limit of the memory_limit variable in php.ini.

These variables can be changed in php.ini and/or .htaccess or with ini_set().

Hope that helps.

Comment: Every time I've had a file upload problem, it's been resolved by paying attention to 1 or 2. +1

Answer (score 6):

The file is removed after the script finishes executing. If you run your script, and then check the /tmp/ folder, the file will not be there no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference this can also happen when Apache does not have access to the destination directory (Remember to change the ACLs !!).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
And I stumbled across the same bug.

In my case, adding a "./" before the $destination solved the problem.

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this issue as well, came across this website for a solution - did not get it tho ;)

I was getting the correct info when viewing `print_r($_FILES)` but was unable to execute `move_uploaded_file`...

I solved the issue by checking the `$upload_file` path attribute in the `move_uploaded_file` function - make sure it is correct otherwise it will not work (mine was incorrect).

Also, the file in the temp location gets removed automatically, I think that is the way PHP works.

I hope this helped.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the temp file is removed after the script ends. I hadn't yet done any move_upload_file... it was working all along.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that you destination folder does not exists or you don't have write permission.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that the file actually is created in /tmp? If you don't have write permission (or the user the script runs as) the file wont be written to /tmp but (I'm guessing) you'll see it during the upload although it's not actually there when the upload finishes.

Edit: $_FILES['file']['error'] - Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0. So check your PHP-version. If it's below 5.1 write to disk might be your problem.

Comment: 100% sure, I can see it being created when I do a larger file upload, but as soon as it's complete it seems to just disappear.

Comment: Ah, just read the rest of comment. We are running 5.2, and, for the moment, the tmp folder is 777

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself. In my case php was uploading to the wrong tmp folder. Instead of using the domains tmp folder (in a virtual host on plesk) it was uploading straight to the OS temporary folder.

Check the settings of your temporary folders

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where 'tmp_name' would say it is being stored in '/private/var/tmp/' but the file would not exist there.

I had to add "E" to my "variables order" in php.ini
; variables_order
   Default Value: "EGPCS"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test to do right before the move_uploaded_file() function:

```php
if (!file_exists("upload")) {
  if (mkdir("upload")) {
    echo "Upload directory created!";
  }
  else {
    die( "Invalid upload directory!" );
  }
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful with your $upload_file. it might have been lack of a "/" when you concatenated folder path and name of file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out PrivateTmp=true in
in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service
After restarting Apache, it will always use system's temporary folder, not a relative one per session.

Comment: Please also include at least a concise note on what the action accomplishes.

Answer (score -2):

Your `form` should use a tag like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="...">
```

Use `multiple/form-data` as `enctype`.

Comment: Not sure, I haven't test this. But from experience, everytime I forget enctype="mult...", I don't have any files. Checking this is easy. Use Live HTTP headers or similar and see if the file is sent.

Comment: Definitely have that in there.

Answer (score -2):

You are using the return value of `move_uploaded_file()` the wrong way round:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_file))
{
    $result['error'] = 'true';
}
else
{
    $result['error'] = 'false';
    $result['file_loc'] = $upload_file;
}
```

Comment: Surely the function returns TRUE if it has run successfully?!