# fail in uploading file using html form

Tags: php, html

Failed to upload file using HTML form:

after I click the submit botton,   I could print out the `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` and `$_FILES["file"]["type"] and ["size"]` and `["tmp_name"]` and
`["error"]` and etc.but I could not find the file in the tmp folder(it should be there by default)!I don't know why.

the html code goes like this:

```
<form action="manage.php?act=getback.questionOpt" target="fileUp" method="post" id="f1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p id="file_u">
      <input type="file" name="file">
        <iframe width="0px" height="0px" name="fileUp" style="display:none">
        </iframe>
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Checkout the complete temp-file like `echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];`?

Comment: When you said you couldnt find the file, did you check the tmp_name'd file or look for the original filename? It may also be its not set to go to /tmp but maybe /var/tmp or other, if its a windows server it maybe the file was seen as a virus and the anti virus has removed it - did you use code to check it was there or did you just look yourself?

Comment: This issue may be occurred due to folder permission...

Comment: Refer this link for more details....
[Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819563/php-file-upload-files-disappearing-from-tmp-before-move-uploaded-files

Comment: can you show your php code too??

Comment: I find the answer,it was folder permission: my php code is "move_uploaded_file("/tmp/phpxdfs","/xxx/xxx/upload");"   but the upload file is unwritable.         A template file in /tmp will be deleted as soon as the php request is finished as @heiglandreas said,so obviously I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files are deleted from the temp-directory unless they are moved or renamed!

There is a small note about that just above the third example on the PHP-Documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Therefore you will not be able to see the file after the request is finished.

Simply renaming the file should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your file? If it is too big and exceeds your server limit, it won't upload. If your server has uploading disabled by default, you will need to turn it on in `php.ini`. This is how:

Open the php.ini file in your editor.

Search for the text string `file_uploads`. You will find something which says `file_uploads = Off | On`. If it says `Off` as the value, problem solved. Otherwise, it could be commented (check for semicolon at start of line). Otherwise:

Change the file permissions of your tmp folder.

Unless you show us the full code, there is nothing else I can do to help you.